# Re-writing URL's with lighttpd

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm using Lighttpd to serve a GET based API that I'm working on, and I'm having some difficulty with re-writing requests.

My API calls are very simple. An example would be :

```
 url:/method/submethod?var1=something&var2=something&key=something
```

This is what I have:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/methodfoo(.*)" => "/index.php$1&method=methodfoo")
```

This works fine if all methods were shallow, but I have `methodfoo/submethod` to deal with. What I'd *like* to do is use a rule that can split this up for me, appending a `&submethod` to the end of the rewritten string.

For instance:

```
url://methodfoo/submethod?foo=bar&foobar=foo
```

Would be re-written to:

```
url://index.php?foo=bar&foobar=foo&method=methodfoo&submethod=foo
```

Can I do that without an explicit rule for each submethod?

***Additional Information:***

Yes, I know I can use a rule like:

```
 "^/methodfoo/(.*)/(.*)" => "/index.php$2&method=methodfoo&submethod=$1"
```

However, That fuglifies (TM) my link structure, as it would have to match:

```
 url://methodfoo/submethod/?foo=bar&foobar=foo
```

When I really want:

```
 url://methodfoo/submethod?foo=bar&foobar=foo
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
url.rewrite-once = ("^/foo/(.*)([/?])(.*)" => "/index.php$2&$3&m=foo&sub=$1")
```

This allows links like:

```
/foo/bar?foo=bar
```

Or

```
/foo/bar/foobar/foo?bar=foo
```

Not sure if that's the best way to do it, but it does let me skip writing a rule for each sub method.